# How to get the actual meridiems in luxonjs?

Tags: luxon

So i tried to get the meridiems on luxon.js because i'm going to move my discord.js bot that is using momentjs to luxonjs because i like it more. But i got the problem that i just can't figure out how to get the meridiems of the timezone that i especify, could you help me out?

I've tried

```
Info.meridiems()
```

but i don't know how to use or what do i do with the Info part,
And then i don't understand the parameters that the give in their documentation as an example

```
Info.meridiems({ locale: 'my' })
```

Answer (score 1):

The meridiem for a DateTime can be accessed by the "a" format token:

```js
DateTime.local().setZone(z).toFormat("a") //=> "PM"
```

The Luxon Info methods are for finding out what the meridiems are called in different human languages.

Answer (score 0):

it was kinda easy but i will not delete this post if someone needs it.

Basically what i did is to get the date in the format that i wanted

```
const time = DateTime.local().setZone('tz').toFormat("HHmmss");
```

in .setZone('tz') you should just put the time zone you want according to the luxon docs.
Then i would just use an if for it

```
const smartMeridiems = (am, pm) =>{
    if(time > 120000){
        pm = 'PM'
        return pm;
    } else{
        am = 'AM'
        return am;
    }
}
```

And that is basically it